# Difference between collection.find().stream() and collection.find().batchSize(100).stream()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

what is the difference between between collection.find().stream() and  collection.find().batchSize(100).stream() ?

Comment: Upvoted by me because this didn't really deserve an upvote but it didn't really deserve a downvote either. Somehow balances things out.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some general confusion that I have come across before as to what [`.batchSize()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) is actually for. The common confusion is that it is something like [`.limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) which is not really helped by this note in the documentation:

> **NOTE**:
>   Specifying 1 or a negative number is analogous to using the limit() method.

While that statement is basically true for that example point, the general purpose is something different.

When iterating a "cursor" or using the [.stream()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) API, which is an implementation of the node.js [stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) readable interface ( and the default from version 2.0 cursors ), there is an underlying optimization of the driver when communicating with the server using this interface.

When you use a cursor `.next()` or the ["data" `.on()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) method for a stream, this does not actually go back to the server and just get the next document in the result set. What it actually does is fetch a "batch" of documents in the cursor corresponding to the "batchSize" given as an argument.

This allows you to modify the default value here and "change" the default to something more optimized to your own process.

Unlike methods such as [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) this does not attempt to read the whole result set in a single database call ( actually never does under the hood really ) into a variable in memory. The cursor and stream methods allow processing of "cursors" where the results are fethced in "batches" and usually processed "individually".